# Redux Authorization Handle with custom Middleware

Tags: api, redux, authorization, middleware, unauthorized

I need to make my redux API calls headers centralized. I mean i need a custom middleware that works before each api call and get token from 'Local Storage' and put it in current api call's header. I found some examples when i googled but i also need 401 unauthorized handling. After each api calls if i get 401 unauthorized response then the middleware clears the local storage. I will appreciated your helps, thank you. I have found some examples like below but i need it also after api call for handle 401 unauthorized situation.

```
const authInterceptor = ({ dispatch }) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.status === 401) {
    dispatch(actions.removeJwt());
  } else {
    next(action);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution :). Below link is useful for me. It is a custom middleware which works for each api call. Also it provides api.then.catch for passed api call argument. so i can handle the dispatch here for pending, success and failure types. I also can handle 401 unauthorized because of error handling in here.

[creating custom redux middleware](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-your-first-redux-middleware-with-ease-a75e6b1384db/)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle 4xx responses with error handling. For example if you use axios api, you can use global response handler.

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => successHandler(response),
  error => errorHandler(error)
)
```

For more information: [Axios response and error interceptors](https://dev.to/teroauralinna/global-http-request-and-response-handling-with-the-axios-interceptor-30ae)